# Choose Trie or HashMap for storing a word frequency list?

Tags: java, hashmap, trie

I have a txt file containing 1 million English word with their frequencies in this format:

good   345667
bad    456777
...

I　need to store it using either a HashMap or a Trie data structure in Java. Later on I need to look up words from the list without other operations. My understanding is that, the look up is slower for HashMap than Trie, but Trie will take up more memory usage, and the implementation of a Trie also takes effort, while HashMap already is ready for use. For production code, do you have any advice or suggestions on what data structures best suit for this situation? Thanks in advance.

Also, HashMap allows for "constant time" for lookup. Is it really slower than a Trie for English words?

Comment: *"My understanding is that, the lookup is slower for HashMap than Trie"* where are you getting this?

Comment: See wikipedia, "Looking up data in a trie is faster in the worst case", "A trie can also be used to replace a hash table..."

Comment: @user697911 isn't the worst case a constant hashing function, resulting in linear time lookup?  So yes, of course lookups are slower in the worst case.

Comment: I found this quite interesting: https://github.com/jpountz/tries/wiki/Benchmark ... as far as I got, the project contains all the mentioned implementations, so you might want to benchmark (speed, memory) using your particular data.

Comment: Great benchmark data. It seems Trie are much more space efficient and HashMap is fastest. Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: @user697911: *"but Trie will take up more memory usage"*  Well, that would really depend on your data. If many of your strings share the same prefixes, then you trie is going to be space-efficient.  And if your data do not share the same prefixes, then the question as to what they're doing in a trie would need to be asked : )

Answer (score 7):

> My understanding is that, the look up is slower for HashMap than Trie, but Trie will take up more memory usage

This is incorrect. Assuming a good hash function, a lookup in a HashMap will require a small constant number of random accesses to main memory, irrespective of the size of the table, or the length of its keys. A trie, in contrast, will require an access to main memory for each letter in the key. Therefore, a trie will cause more cache misses - and in cache misses will dominate the overall lookup cost on modern hardware.

A trie can save memory if the keys are long and share many common prefixes.

A trie also supports prefix queries.

In your case, keys are short, and you don't need prefix queries, so you won't benefit from a trie.

Answer (score 4):

Given a good hash function (which the `String` class surely has,) a Hashmap will have faster lookup time than a Trie.

From Wikipedia, you'll read:

> Looking up data in a trie is faster in the worst case, O(m) time (where m is the length of a search string), compared to an imperfect hash table. An imperfect hash table can have key collisions. A key collision is the hash function mapping of different keys to the same position in a hash table. The worst-case lookup speed in an imperfect hash table is O(N) time, but far more typically is O(1), with O(m) time spent evaluating the hash.

So, a Hashmap with many collisions is slower than a trie.  However, that only happens when your key has a poor hash function.  If you're using `String` objects as the key, you won't have that problem.

A Trie will save you memory. Exactly how much will depend on the composition of your data.  If the data is similar, you'll have greater memory savings.  If the data is varied, there'll be less savings. This is because the prefixes are shared for strings with common prefixes.

So if memory is adequate, and you've a good hash function, use a Hashmap.

Otherwise, use a `Trie`.

Comment: Since the word entry is large (one million), a Trie might save some space, because prefix are shared. Not really sure which one is more space efficient though.

Comment: It should be noted that a hastable is only O(1) in theory.  With large tables it begins to break down.

Answer (score 3):

1 million is not really such a big number these days for the number of entries in an in-memory data structure, at least on a server, desktop or laptop. On a phone or tab/pad it may become painful.

Implementing an efficient trie is anything but trivial and may end up counter to what you hope for with regards of performance and memory usage. Just imagine: in every node you need a jump-table which branches on potentially every character to a child node. What is your potential character set: all of Unicode, european, ascii, lowercase and uppercase, only lowercase. The further to the left your answer is, the larger the jump-tables become. But even with just lowercase a-z you need a jumptable in every node with up to 26 entries. Speed requires to reserve 26*4 bytes in every node. Space efficiency rather pushes you to store the table somehow sparse. Higher up in the trie, likely all slots are needed and a sparse array would be a waste of space and time. Closer to the leaves, less and less slots need to point to child nodes and stay empty, so a full and fast table would be a waste of space.

Java's HashMap has quite some history and is probably one of the best tested, commented, critized and improved implementations of a hash map available. For your requirement I would clearly start with it, possibly experiment a bit with the loadFactor and only if you run into serious problems provably due to the HashMap, I would invest time in a trie.

Comment: As for load factor, since the entry number is known, 1 million. So it's best to set a load factor of 1, and capacity = 1 milliion?

Comment: As far as I understand it, the loadFactor is the number of slots in the HashMap that have data. If you set it to 1, your HashMap will have lots of collisions. While this is space efficient, the lookup will tend to be more and more linear search. For speed, you need a small loadFactor to reduce the number of collisions.

Comment: Hey, load factor has nothing to do with collision. It represents at what level the HashMap capacity should be doubled.  The load factor is a measure of how full the hash table is allowed to get before its capacity is automatically increased.

Comment: The loadFactor is all about collisions. With a capacity of just 2, a loadFactor of 1 and 1 element in the HashMap, the 2nd element you store has a chance of 50% to create a collison.
If you set the loadFactor to 1/2-epsilon, the capacity will be  increased to 4 after storing the first element and your chance for a collision on storing the second element is only 25%.

Comment: I am not sure your way of thinking collision is correct. The default loadFactor = 0.75. Does that mean in most HashMap uses, there will be lots of collisions? Collisions do happen, but it's rare with a good hash function. In theory, a good enough hash function can ensure 0 collision with a loadFactor=1.

Comment: As far as I remember, a perfectly random distribution is the best hash function you can get assuming your input samples are evenly distributed and further assuming that the cardinality of the set you are sampling is much much larger than your the number of slots in your hash table. This is usually the case. If N-1 slots of N slots in your hash map have data, the loadFactor is N-1/N. The chance that the next random number hits any of those used slots is N-1/N, which is exactly the loadFactor.

Comment: Do you mean with loadFActor=0.75 and the table is already 75% full, the chance of colliding is 75% for any new key?

Comment: Actually, since I care more about the lookup time, after the table is loaded, the table will stay stable. The collision only matters for the initial loading. So to achieve best space and time efficient, setting loadFactor=1 seems to be sensible choice of this situation. Any further advice?

Comment: If you do a binary radix tree the "jump table" is only ever 2 entries, and, for the general case, the jump table in any node only needs to be the size of the "span" for that node.  But it is a good point that Java is not a real good choice for a trie implementation language, where bit twiddling of the nodes is useful.

Comment: You can hold a map in each node so it won't have empty characters but just the characters that are needed.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the operative word here is "million".  For that many entries hashing begins to suffer performance problems, while a trie maintains it's log(N) characteristic, even if the machine begins paging heavily.  And a trie is more suited for a disk-based table (with caching).

But implementing an efficient (and reliable) trie is fairly difficult.  Not for the faint of heart.