# frequency of letters in column python - speed optimization

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I want to calculate the frequency that each element (a character) occurs at each position, in a similar manner to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21103320/1274242). This is my current solution:

```
import pandas as pd
sequences = ['AATC',
             'GCCT',
             'ATCA',
             'TGAG',
             'CGGA']
f = zip(*sequences)
counts = [{letter: column.count(letter) for letter in column} for column in f]
counts=pd.DataFrame(counts).transpose()
print counts
   0  1  2  3
A  2  1  1  2
C  1  1  2  1
G  1  2  1  1
T  1  1  1  1
```

(pandas is there because it is my preferred output). However, since I am dealing with hundreds of thousand, and potentially millions of sequences (10 characters or more in length), this is somewhat slow: it takes 20 minutes for ~100^3 sequences, and several hours in my real dataset. So I thought I could improve the speed by resorting to pandas since I am converting anyway to dataframe anyway: `df = pd.DataFrame(f).transpose()`.

This strategy turns out to be even slower:

*Solution 1*

```
import time

start_time = time.time()
counts = [{letter: column.count(letter) for letter in column} for column in f]
counts=pd.DataFrame(counts).transpose()
print(counts)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
--- 0.00820517539978 seconds ---
```

*Solution 2*

```
start_time = time.time()
df = pd.DataFrame(f).transpose()
print df.apply(lambda col: col.value_counts())
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
--- 0.0104739665985 seconds ---
```

So the question is: is there a way to optimize this? I looked into multiprocessing for `df.apply(lambda col: col.value_counts())` but there seems easy to be no easy implementation.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104338/choose-trie-or-hashmap-for-storing-a-word-frequency-list, use a frequency Trie, it should be efficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`column.count(letter) for letter in column` will be very slow, because it's repeating the same calculation many, many times; and `pandas` works best with lots of rows and few columns.  So if you keep the data in that format, it should be pretty quick.  Here's an example with 10^6 rows:

```
>>> seqs = [''.join([random.choice("ACGT") for i in range(10)]) for j in range(10**6)]
>>> seqs[:5]
['CTTAAGCGAA', 'TATAGGATTT', 'AAACGGTGAG', 'AGTAGGCTAC', 'CTGTTCTGCG']
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([list(s) for s in seqs])
>>> df.head()
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  C  T  T  A  A  G  C  G  A  A
1  T  A  T  A  G  G  A  T  T  T
2  A  A  A  C  G  G  T  G  A  G
3  A  G  T  A  G  G  C  T  A  C
4  C  T  G  T  T  C  T  G  C  G
>>> %time z = df.apply(pd.value_counts)
CPU times: user 286 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 286 ms
Wall time: 285 ms
>>> z
        0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9
A  249910  250452  249971  250136  250048  250025  249763  249787  250498  251008
C  249437  249556  250270  249884  250245  249975  249888  250432  249867  249516
G  250740  250277  250414  249847  250080  249447  249901  249638  250010  249480
T  249913  249715  249345  250133  249627  250553  250448  250143  249625  249996
```

Comment: Wow! That is lightning fast and very elegant syntax. In a real dataset it went from taking days (between and 4), to a couple of minutes. I would have giving you 2 up-votes if I could. Thank you @DSM.

Answer (score 1):

so i did some tests, and here's a way takes about 40% as much time:

```
def count_test():  # what you do
    f = zip(*sequences)
    counts = [{letter: column.count(letter) for letter in column} for column in f]
    counts=pd.DataFrame(counts).transpose()
    return counts


def new_way():
    df = pd.DataFrame(map(list, sequences))
    res = {}
    for c in df.columns:
        res[c] = df[c].value_counts()
    return pd.DataFrame(res)
```

if you want to `multiprocess` this you can always divide your list of sequences into chunks, farm them out to various processes, and then sum up at the end. there might be some memory constraints here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since the input is given row-by-row I thought that not transposing might be natural and save time. Secondly, I would keep the data type as string and only later convert the results to a Pandas object.

Imagine you have `numseq` strings with length `numcols` then access to the elements in a column is feasable with a slice of size `numcols`. Like this (I reuse the sequence creation code from DSM here):

```
numseq = 1*10**6      # number of sequences
numcols = 10          # length of single code sequence
letters = ['A','C','G','T']
# create input sequences
sequences = [''.join([random.choice("ACGT") for i in range(numcols)]) for j in range(numseq)]
counts = [[] * len(letters) for j in range(numcols)]

T2 = ''.join(sequences)
for i in range(numcols):
    counts[i] = [T2[i::numcols].count(letter) for letter in letters]
```

I compared the runtime with the original method of counting consecutively over the transposed string (not a Pandas object) and noticed a ratio of 1:4 on my PC @ 10**6 sequences.